# AJAX readystatechange listener for IE7+8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

```js
(function (send) {

     XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {

         this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {

             console.log('readyState changed');

         }, false);

         send.apply(this, arguments);
     };

})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

This works, but it seems to be affecting other frameworks (like jQuery). When I use the code above, my jQuery ajax calls doen't complete (IE7 + IE8).

Is there any way to give the event a new alias so that it doesn't cause any conflicts (I'm just assuming that this is the problem)?

And I can't use `this.onreadystatechange`, since jQuery is overwriting it (see Fiddle).

As soon as I bind the event listener, the code seems to fail silently so I can't use the console to debug.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8su2/459/)

[Compare in ie8 vs ie9 mode and notice that the console is empty in ie8](http://jsfiddle.net/L8su2/459/show)

The reason why I need this is that I want a global ajax handler for another framework (GWT). I use jQuery just for testing it now.

Edit: Looks like only ie9 supports `addEventListener`. However, `attachEvent` doesn't seem to exist on the XHR object in ie7-8.

Comment: i`m blind sorry for that answer i try to find problem, i dont know why?... you replaced XMLHttpRequest.send and you are last person that change onreadystatechange and nobody could change it after you..!! but as you explain not worked.. i change onload and its true & worked.. and i check jquery source, jquery not overwriting on onreadystatechange and only overwrite onload & onerror of XHR

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh jQuery sets it to `$.noop` which in an empty function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noop/

Comment: yep i found line and found problem, the problem is when you send request by jquery, it check timeout and set onreadystatechange to noop ( jquery.basis.js, line 5240 ):
setTimeout(function() {
// Check to see if the request is still happening
if ( xhr && !requestDone ) {
   onreadystatechange( "timeout" );
}
}, s.timeout);

& if you set timeout to 0 youre problem solve in jquery :D

Comment: @MehdiYeganeh Hehe thanks, but as I mentioned earlier, I just used jQuery as an example.

Comment: comment this line console.log('readyState changed');
I have found console.log() statements causing problems in IE.

Answer (score 1):

We have had similar issue with jquery failing on IE8. I assume that you are making a cross domain request. Jquery does ajax through the XMLHttpRequest , but IE8 has replaced XMLHttpRequest object with XDomainRequest and jquery folks do not support it.So for IE8 , you will have to modify the code to use XDomainRequest with jquery.

see the links

[Using jquery ajax for IE8](http://graphicmaniacs.com/note/getting-a-cross-domain-json-with-jquery-in-internet-explorer-8-and-later/)

Comment: Thanks but jQuery should handle this internally now. Also, `XMLHttpRequest` is supported down to IE7.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned above; I'm not looking for a jQuery solution. I'm using GWT. I just used jQuery for demonstation purpose.

Comment: jquery will not handle it internally. They have no plans to support IE8 , see this bug report --> http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283

Comment: If you are using GWT too , you should check if GWT supports XDomainRequest. My intuitions tell me this has something to do with IE8 not having the XMLHttpRequest for ajax transport.

Comment: The lack of XDomainRequest support is irrelevant in my opinion, since jQuery is using XMLHttpRequests, which are working in IE7+8 as well. The reason that my code above fails is because it's only IE9 that have support for `addEventlistener`, while IE7+8 uses `attachEvent`.